# How to create a column that present the delta if it's greater than a specific number from two columns that each one of them is from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,
 
table1:

```
  ID  |  Value1  |  Value2
----------------------------
   1  |   152    |   187
   2  |   348    |   457
   3  |   214    |   192
```

table2:

```
  ID  |  Value1  |  Value2
----------------------------
   1  |   196    |   242
   2  |   233    |   132
   3  |   451    |   121
```

I want to create a query to select or create a new temporary table that will contains the id and the values columns if the delta between them is greater than 50,
so it should be:

```
if table1.Value1 - table2.Value1 >= 50 or table2.Value1 - table1.Value1 >= 50
```

Then I want the delta value to be presented as Value1 and the same for Value2,
Your help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a free coding service.  Make attempt to create your query, do some research.  Then if you're stuck, post your query so we can try to help you.

Comment: I did try to find a solution by myself, personally I don't see any problem to get help whether it's for homework or not but I respect the rules so I don't expect anyone to solve it, a hint would be good enough :)

Comment: hint: use `IF()` function for column expression https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Hint:  do not use `if()`.  It is not needed for the question and if you did want conditional logic, use the ANSI standard `case` expression instead.

Comment: @Barmar plainly, that’s not quite true :-(

Comment: I joined both tables and create a temp one that contains the relevant data, it seems good for now and I think I have the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1) >= 50;
```

With this, you should be able to add in the difference in the `SELECT` and any similar conditions you also want on `value2`.